# What are the best tools for Sql Server version control

Tags: sql-server-2008, version-control, visual-studio-2010

After reading [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/is-your-database-under-version-control.html) post, and the suggestion to use `Team Edition for Database Professionals`, I want to know is there any equivalent to this for SQL server 2008 / Visual stuio 2010 ultimate.

I'm looking for tool need to do all the thing that Jeff mention in [his](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/is-your-database-under-version-control.html) article:

- Create test data.
- Schema comparison.
- Data comparison.
- Database unit testing.
- Refactoring.
- Integrated T-SQL editor, a first class language construct in the IDE, just like C# and VB.NET.

For the full details look on this article: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/is-your-database-under-version-control.html

---

It seems that Visual Studio 2010 (and 2008) have very strong approach for this issue. I don't know if it the best option that exist, but it definitely good.

Here are [Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193266.aspx) and [Walkthrouge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833258.aspx) to learn how to start using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS 2010 Premium and Ultimate have that built in (Expand database development link)

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products

In short, your database project gets checked into source control, and you deploy to production from the database project.

If you are looking for something that is to be used outside of VS2010 then redgate has a beta 
http://www.red-gate.com/Products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm

Comment: Can you point me to an article that describe how to use that?

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/143624.aspx

Comment: I'm looking for the best tool, and integration with visual studio is always an advantage.

Comment: @raj that link is covering vs2008.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/07/29/visual-studio-2010-database-projects.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check for the below link  :

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/is-your-database-under-version-control.html

Tools for the read gate
Sql Compare - Compares and synchronizes SQL database schemas.
Sql Data Compare : Compares and synchronizes SQL database contents.

link of 14 day trial version : https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/downloads/downloadform.aspx?download=sqlcompare

Comment: I'm asking because this link. this article is great, and want to know the options/tools that I have in April 2010.

Comment: Check the above link But this are not free to download only 14day trail version available

Comment: Do you think they are better on vs2010 built in tools?

Comment: after view tsf i think tsf is better than red gate tool - this is my personal view

Answer (score 2):

I've just developed this [new tool](http://servantt.com/?so) (**free**) that helps you to easily **extract scripts** for SQL databases, can do **comparison**, can **launch WinMerge** for quickly comparing scripts to live database, and can also **synch differences** both updating the scripts or applying the changes to the database (except for tables, which would involve more complexity and more risks).

**Servantt is the WinMerge for comparing SQL Server Databases to Version-Controlled Scripts.**

It supports and encourages best-practices in software development:

- Keeping Database objects under version-control (*)
- Removing access rights from developers on production environments
- DBA review of changes in procedures/views for performance bottlenecks and naming standards
- Naming objects using fully qualified identifiers and bracketed delimiters (it fixes the CREATE PROCEDURE/VIEW/FUNCTION/etc scripts)

(*) Scripts are saved into a local folder that can be a working copy of Git, Subversion, TFS, Source Safe, or any other VCS.

Free Download: [http://servantt.com](http://servantt.com/?so)

Comment: I'd love to hear feedback about it. Critics and suggestions are welcome (either by comments here, or by the email address at the product page).

Answer (score 0):

I use visual studio. eveloper database per developer, using the VIsual Studio 2010 Ultimate database tools - works nicely, "even" against TFS 2010 ;)

Comment: Do you have a kind of database type project in your solution?