# Make versions of MS SQL Server Stored procedures and functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, versioning

I have problem that is all my team members are altering the Sps and functions and
some conflicts occurred through the development

is there anyway or tool to store and get all version of them ?

the problem is before releasing the new version, i don't want a tool to compare difference between two databases like what Red gate SQL_Compare

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best tools for Sql Server version control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718919/what-are-the-best-tools-for-sql-server-version-control)

Comment: @shahkalpesh i don't know what is the exact term that describe my problem ! but yes something to control versions

Comment: yeah you need to set that up before you start messing about :p

Comment: Put your stored procedures into SQL scripts and then store them in a version control system (Subversion, Git, ...). You might also want to look in a complete schema change management solution like Liquibase or Flyway

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of the features in Visual Studio and TFS(or any other source control mechanisms). All that you need to do is to

- Create a SQLServer DB Project in Visual studio and configure it to
  your desired database.
- Bind the project to a source control (TFS,
  SVN etc.,)

Every time you have a change in DB, you can just compare the changes using .scmp file and click update.

You may refer this post for more information: 
http://candordeveloper.com/2013/01/08/creating-a-sql-server-database-project-in-visual-studio-2012/